# "NameError: name 'table' is not defined", trying to add numbers over a loop to a string

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a range of values and have it be attached to the name before the equal sign.

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    table[i] = "hello"
    print(table[i])
```

I want the result to be

```
table1 = "hello"
table2 = "hello"
table3 = "hello"
table4 = "hello"
table5 = "hello"
```

How can I do that? I am getting the error "NameError: name 'table' is not defined"

Is this the correct way to do it? or is there a better way.

Comment: python 2 is no longer supported....  I suggest not using it

Comment: Well do you know how to do the example in python 3 atleast?

Comment: use @luangtatipsy answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code you provided is a syntax of Python 3. The error happens while you try to access the variable `table` which is not defined (in your snippet). What you need is string formatting to display your expected result. In addition, if you need `i` to start with 1 to 5, you have to set the `xrange` to `(1, 6)`.

```py
for i in xrange(1, 6):
    print 'table{} = "hello"'.format(i)
```

Output:

```bash
table1 = "hello"
table2 = "hello"
table3 = "hello"
table4 = "hello"
table5 = "hello"
```